# Сделать DataGrid в C# WPF такой, как в C# WinForms (DatagridView)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать DataGrid с 4 колонками с возможностью добавления, редактирования, удаления строк именно так, как это сделано в стандартном DataGridView? Без сохранения, ничего другого не нужно. Спасибо

Comment: Не проще ли в таком случае захостить оригинальную DGV прямо из винформ? Если уж у вас такие жесткие требования... Или вообще писать проект под винформы. Другими словами, повторить контрол по столь размытым требованиям - задача не простая, ну если пытаться вытащить это этого полноую идентичность по визуалу и поведению. В WPF полно других инструментов, кроме DataGrid, возможно если вы переосмыслите подход к задаче, выяснится, что DataGrid вам вовсе и не нужна. Я практически не знаю серьезных приложений, где реально нужны таблицы, ну кроме Excel и всяких 1С бухгалтерий. Конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: `DataGrid` нативно поддерживает добавление, редактирование и удаление. Для того чтобы это работало, ничего дополнительно делать не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь использовать простой <kbd>DataGrid</kbd>. Создаётся он так:

```
<DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First column"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Second column"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Third column"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Ещё советую изучить <kbd>**ItemsControl**</kbd>.

Comment: На самом деле, да, я могу использовать такой случай, но я не могу так, как в DataGridView - добавлять строки при записи информации, менять записи. В данном случае просто хэдеры колонок и ничего более